# ASP.NET MVC 4,contoso university example, how to sort the filtered result and display correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am studying asp.net mvc 4 and following the Contoso University tutorial and I am at part 3 of 10. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Question I have in particular is about the filtering part. I noticed that when I have a search string and click search, it will give me results I want. But when I click Last name or Enrollment to sort the result, it will give me the sorted list including all students. The following is the Controller code:

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
var students = from s in db.Students
               select s;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    students = students.Where(s =>s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                           || s.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
}
switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "name_desc":
        students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
        break;
    case "Date":
        students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
        break;
    case "date_desc":
        students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
        break;
    default:
        students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
        break;
}

return View(students.ToList());
```

}

When I was in the debug mode,   I noticed that even though the search box still had the original search string in it, the searchString passed into Index()d of controller was null. How can I change the code so that I can sort the filtered result? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the filter to the ViewBag and update your sort links to include the filter

```
ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

@Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder=ViewBag.NameSortParm, searchString=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
```

Comment: Excellent, Worked! Thank you!